# How can I implement a marker trait on a struct with a lifetime?

Tags: struct, rust, traits, lifetime

Given a struct that has a lifetime, how can I provide a marker-trait for it.

```rust
struct UserProvidedID<'a> { field: &'a str, }
impl warp::reject::Reject for UserProvidedID<'_> {}
```

Note this trait otherwise does what I want, I just want to "mark" it. I don't want to change the lifetime semantics.

Comment: `impl<'a> Foo for UserProvidedID<'a> {}` should work!?

Comment: @user2722968 I get `[Error] [E0478] lifetime bound not satisfied but lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime`

Comment: `pub trait Reject: fmt::Debug + Sized + Send + Sync + 'static {}` so Reject requires static lifetime, I think

Comment: Yes, `warp::reject::Reject` cannot be used with borrowed data. The reason for this is probably the fact that any type implementing `Reject` must be accessible inside warp runtime, not only in handler which creates it.

Comment: This is a dupe of [rust lifetime parameter must outlive the static lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880262/rust-lifetime-parameter-must-outlive-the-static-lifetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [definition of `Reject`](https://docs.rs/warp/0.3.1/warp/reject/trait.Reject.html) is the following:

```
pub trait Reject: Debug + Sized + Send + Sync + 'static { }
```

Notice the `'static`, which means any type you want to implement `Reject` for needs to accept the `'static` lifetime. Therefore, the only possibility is to [use the static lifetime in your struct too](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5840e19d5411818ffeca3ad6028aeada):

```rust
struct UserProvidedID<'a> { field: &'a str, }
impl Reject for UserProvidedID<'static> {}
```

This might not be what you want, but given the definition of `Reject`, in a crate I assume is not yours, this is your only option.